# Accessing props func outside of the React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using an npm called `react-zoom-pan-pinch` which has multiple func as props. but I want to call some of them outside of the component.
how can I call the component functions in my own function?

```
const handleShiftClick = () => {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
      zoomOut();// component function
    }
};

return (
    <div className="App">
      <TransformWrapper initialScale={1}>
        // functions
        {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform, ...rest }) => (
          <>
            <div className="tools">
              <Hotkeys keyName={keys.ZOOM_IN} onKeyDown={() => zoomIn()}>
                <button onClick={() => zoomIn()}>+ key</button>
              </Hotkeys>
            </div>

            <TransformComponent></TransformComponent>
          </>
        )}
      </TransformWrapper>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Seems you can use a [React ref on the TransformWrapper](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to access the [handlers](https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/docs/docs-handlers--page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const transformRef = useRef(null);
const handleShiftClick = () => {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
      transformRef.current?.zoomOut();// component function
    }
};
return (
    <div className="App">
      <TransformWrapper initialScale={1} ref={transformRef}>
        {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform, ...rest }) => (
          <>
            <div className="tools">
              <Hotkeys keyName={keys.ZOOM_IN} onKeyDown={() => zoomIn()}>
                <button onClick={() => zoomIn()}>+ key</button>
              </Hotkeys>
            </div>

            <TransformComponent></TransformComponent>
          </>
        )}
      </TransformWrapper>
    </div>
  )
```

TransformWrapper support forwardRef

Comment: forwardRef works well, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass them to a outer function.

```
const manageKeyPress = (funcs) => {
    return (event) => {
        const {zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform} = funcs;
        if(event.shiftKey) {
           zoomOut();
        }
    }

};

return (
    <div className="App">
      <TransformWrapper initialScale={1}>
        // functions
        {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform, ...rest }) => (
          <>
            <div className="tools">
              <Hotkeys keyName={keys.ZOOM_IN} onKeyDown={manageKeyPress({zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform})}>
                <button onClick={() => zoomIn()}>+ key</button>
              </Hotkeys>
            </div>

            <TransformComponent></TransformComponent>
          </>
        )}
      </TransformWrapper>
    </div>
  );
```